# Windows 7 slow after password entering - perhaps Domain Controller timeout? How to decrease?

Tags: windows-7, windows

When I boot my Laptop (Windows 7, Core i7, 8 GB RAM, SSD), after entering password it takes about 1 minute to continue.
The PC is apparently idling, no HDD LED.

I presume it is looking for the Domain Controller, as it is a company laptop.

How can I decrease the timeout looking for the DC, as I am most of the time outside of the company?

Comment: install the WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), run WPRUI.exe select **CPU, Disk, fileIO, network** and under perf scenario **Boot**. Run 1 boot trace, after you're back in windows, compress the ETL in a 7z/RAR (to reduce the file size), upload the compressed file to onedrive, dropbox, create a share link and pots the link here. I'll try to look where the laptop boots slowly

Comment: Does it boot faster when you are in the company network?

Comment: have you captured the boot trace?